# How do you add a new folder to app/ in ember-cli?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I want to add an SDK type to ember-cli to wrap up complex ajax calls into a simple javascript wrapper returning a known format of POJO that can be tested.

I added an app/sdk/login.js and exported a simple empty class there. When I import it elsewhere I get a broccoli error:

ENOENT, no such file or directory 'F:\Projects\insm-ui\tmp\tree_merger-tmp_dest_
dir-JOQL1Mli.tmp\sdk\login.js'

Standard ember-cli way:

```
// sdk/login.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export function initialize(container, application) {
  container.register('sdk:login', LoginSdk);
}

export default Ember.Object.extend({
});

// somewhere else
import LoginSdk from 'sdk/login'; // this line errors as above in broccoli
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: How are you exporting? How are you importing? Can't help with incomplete information.

Comment: Question is what's the correct way, not what's wrong with mine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use relative paths for local files in your import statement. You didn't give the path to the "somewhere else" file. But let's say it's a controller at `app/controllers/my-controller.js` and your sdk is at `app/sdk/login.js`.

You could import it in the controller like:

```
import LoginSdk from '../sdk/login';
```

Comment: He shoots, he scores!! Thanks, Jake